# What is the probability of two people who hit with probabilities p and q neither hitting their targets?

Tags: probability, self-study, bernoulli-distribution

What is the probability of two people who hit with probabilities p and q respectively neither hitting their targets?

A is the event that person one hits ~ Ber(p)
B is the event that person two hits ~ Ber(q).

I thought the answer is $1-p \cdot q = P((A \cap B)^c)=p((A^C \cup B^c) = P(A^C)+P(B^C) - p(A^C \cap B^C) = (1-p)+(1-q) - (1-p)*(1-q)$

The textbook says $(1-p)(1-q)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without giving it away (because this should be tagged as [self-study](/questions/tagged/self-study), the problem was in this step:

$$1-p \cdot q = P((A \cap B)^c)\text{.}$$

On the right, you’ve written “the probability of not (both A and B),” which isn’t what you intended. That’s *either one of them—or both—missing*, not *both of them missing*—which is what you want. The latter is equivalent to “neither of them hitting”; the former is equivalent to “at most one of them hitting”.